# Repeated Synchronous AJAX calls based on response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I know there are plenty of examples on how to make synchronous AJAX calls (using deferred promises) but my issue is a little different. Here is what I am trying to do

1. Make an AJAX call
2. If the response contains a certain value then loop around again and make another AJAX call with different parameters. Value of Parameters will be dependent upon the response from the first AJAX call so have to wait before making the second AJAX call.
3. If the response contains (exit = true) then exit the loop.

I understand that if the server never returns condition 3 we would be in an endless loop.

How do I continue looping on an AJAX call until a the response from the AJAX call contains a certain value?

Comment: put your ajax call in a function and have a while loop execute the function until X condition is met. Make sure to set async: false in your jquery ajax call to ensure synchronous processing. A note on that, though, if you are using synchronous processing, it will lock your browser out. You will not be able to click, scroll, etc. until your while loop is done executing.

Comment: "synchronous" don't you mean asynchronous?

Comment: …or maybe "sequential"? Promises are never synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code to make the AJAX call in a named function. The callback function of the AJAX checks whether the response contains `exit = true`. If not, it calls the named function again to make the next AJAX call with the updated function.

```
function call_ajax(params ...) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        data: { whatever },
        dataType: 'json'
        success: function(response) {
            if (!response.exit) {
                // calculate new parameters
                call_ajax(new_params ...);
            }
        }
    })
}
```